# When A sends a signed transaction to B, is the data operation visible in the transaction ?

Tags: transactions

When A sends a signed transaction to B, is the data operation visible in the transaction ?  Are the details of the transaction visible to B ? We are planning to put some key value pairs in the transaction , and we don't want B to be able to see that data, but B can submit that transaction for execution.

Answer (score 3):

All transaction details are always visible to anyone. It's one of the pillars of public blockchains.

Besides that, a transaction can hold only a relatively small amount of additional data (see [memo](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#memo) field), so it won't be enough for you. However, you can store the data on your server, hash it and attach the hash value to a transaction as `memo`.

You might want to use [IPFS](https://ipfs.io) to extend the case further and make the data storage fully decentralized.